# Connection with postgres by spring boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, gradle, database-connection

I have a Postgres server running on 127.0.0.1:51282. When I build this project I get org.postgresql.util.PSQLException and communicate that connection attempt has failed.
Here is my configuration:

```
application.properties:
spring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://172.0.0.1:51282/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=kurwa123
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Postgres console:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVpEB.png)

Gradle configuration:

```
dependencies { 
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa' 
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf' 
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web' 
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools' 
    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.18' 
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') { 
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine' 
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for ur answers

Comment: dependencies {
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
 developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
 compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.18'
 testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
  exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
 }
these are my dependencies

Comment: Could you give us the full stacktrace?

Comment: Did you try to connect by using pgAdmin or another tool? Just to make sure it is possible to connect. Also, in the picture, I see you use `db` as the database name. With the provided configuration, Spring might not find your database.

Comment: you should be connecting to 127.0.0.1 instead of 172.0.0.1 in your app properties.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/6T4MKuPn here is full stacktrace

Comment: Yes Im using pgAdmin and I have 2 databases, db and postgres

Comment: @Oskar I have put a complete answer. Have a look on it.

Answer (score 0):

When initiating the spring application, it should be below the image.

- [[Link to create spring boot demo application using spring
  initializer.]](https://start.spring.io/)

[image: Spring Initializer]

Now click on the "GENERATE" button to download the project. Then unzip it and open it using a convenient IDEA. (Ex: IntelliJ)

> Here, you have to add dependencies as I have done. `PostgreSQL Driver SQL` allows Java programs to connect to a PostgreSQL database using
> standard, database-independent Java code. You can download and install
> the latest [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/download/).

**Installing Steps.**

[image: Installing step 1]

[image: installing step 2]

When installing you have to give a password. And keep it in your mind, because that password is needed to connect the server. Furthermore, you have to give the port number for PostgreSQL. Now, the app is installed on your local machine. Then find the app [**pgAdmin 4**] as below mentioned in the image.

[image: pgmyadmin]

Now you can see an interface to enter the password to connect the server as below.

[image: connect server]

Now you can see a red color cross mark. So, we have to connect the database.
[image: disconnected]

So, follow the below steps.

[image]

Now, you can see the notifications which show the successful connection of the server.

[image]

For the moment if you don't have created a database, you can follow the below step.

[image: create db]

Now, you can see the database and the user of the database below.

[image: find DB]

Then we can connect our database with the created spring boot application.

**Database configuration:**

application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/EmployeeDB
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

Here, the port number for PostgreSQL I have given is 5432. You may be different. Therefore put your port number there and the database name also should be the same as the database you have created while doing the above steps. Furthermore, the username and password should be yours.

Now, we have done. Run the application and see.

`Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''`, you can see this in the terminal. If you want to change port number 8080,

`server.port=3000` should be added to the same file.

When changing the port IDEA image with the terminal:

[image: final app run]